# Ecto Changeset Array Type Returns "is invalid" Error

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I'm attempting to insert a list into a field with type `{:array, :string}` but keep receiving a "is invalid" error once the form is submitted. Here's my relevant code:

*Migration*

```
def change do
  alter table(:articles) do
    add :images, {:array, :string}
  end
end
```

*Model*

```
schema "articles" do
  ...
  field :images, {:array, :string}
  ...
end

@required_fields ~w(title content user_id)
@optional_fields ~w(images)

def changeset(model, params \\ :empty) do
  model
  |> cast(params, @required_fields, @optional_fields)
  |> validate_length(:title, max: 78)
  |> strip_unsafe_content(params)
end
...
```

*Controller*

```
def create(conn, %{"article" => %{"images" => nil} = article_params}) do
  changeset = Article.changeset(%Article{}, article_params)

  case Repo.insert(changeset) do
    {:ok, article} ->
      conn
      |> put_flash(:info, "Article created successfully.")
      |> redirect(to: article_path(conn, :show, article))
    {:error, changeset} ->
      render(conn, "new.html", changeset: changeset)
  end
end

def create(conn, %{"article" => %{"images" => images} = article_params}) do
  images = String.split(images, ",", trim: true)
  changeset = Article.changeset(%Article{}, article_params)
              |> Ecto.Changeset.change(images: images)

  case Repo.insert(changeset) do
    {:ok, article} ->
      conn
      |> put_flash(:info, "Article created successfully.")
      |> redirect(to: article_path(conn, :show, article))
    {:error, changeset} ->
      render(conn, "new.html", changeset: changeset)
  end
end
```

*Changeset*

```
%Ecto.Changeset{action: :insert,
  changes: %{content: "\tTest",
    images: ["images/articles/hh_2016/1.jpg", "images/articles/hh_2016/2.jpg",
    "images/articles/hh_2016/3.jpg", "images/articles/hh_2016/4.jpg",
    "images/articles/hh_2016/5.jpg", "images/articles/hh_2016/6.jpg",
    "images/articles/hh_2016/7.jpg", "images/articles/hh_2016/8.jpg"],
    title: "Test", user_id: 31}, 
  constraints: [], 
  errors: [images: "is invalid"],
  ...
}
```

I'm guessing that I've missed something basic but can't figure it out. Any help is appreciated! Let me know if you need more code.

Comment: Can you show us how you're calling the `changeset` function (the values for the 2 arguments)?

Comment: My bad, I accidentally left out the controller portion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're passing a string as `images` to `Article.changeset/2` first, which marks `images` as invalid, and then putting a valid value later with `Ecto.Changeset.change/2`, but `Ecto.Changeset.change/2` does not rerun the validations automatically. For your example, you can simply pass the correct `images` value to `Article.changeset/2`:

```
images = String.split(images, ",", trim: true)
changeset = Article.changeset(%Article{}, %{article_params | "images" => images)
```